# Two turtles running 'similar' code at the same time

Tags: netlogo

Ive got this strange issue with my code going on.

In my model i have female (set female true)  and males (set male true).

Upon a particular trigger each will 'become' a disperser (set disperser true).

Dispersers and non dispersers have very different behaviour.

I have tried solving this with different breeds representing the two classes but this has also not worked.

The problem is that one of the turtles e.g. male, will operate accordingly and set disperser to 'false' upon meeting the opposite turtle. However the other will not, and will continue with disperser set 'true'

Im sure it is because once one of the turtles operates the code, it is no longer a 'disperser' and therefore no longer applys to the search criteria of the later turtle but every work around ive tried has resulted in the same problem or nobody errors.

```
to search-for partner
    if male = true [ set potential-mates other turtles with [female = true
    and disperser = true]
    if female = true [ set potential-mates other turtles with [male = true
    and disperser = true]

    let chosen-mate min-one-of potential-mates [distance myself]

    if any? potential-mates [
        set heading towards chosen-mate]

    if male = true [ if any? other turtles-here with [female = true and
        disperser = true] [set disperser false]

    if female = true [ if any? other turtles-here with [male = true and
        disperser = true] [set disperser false]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely convinced I know what you want to do, but I think you are asking to set disperser to false for both turtles. In which case you want code that looks something like this (not tested):

```
if male
[ let my-partner one-of other turtles-here with [female and disperser ]
  if my-partner != nobody
  [ set disperser false
    ask partner [ set disperser false ]
  ]
]
```

You should probably also consider separating the 'search for partner' code from the 'found partner' code. Also, you may be better off having them check if they have a partner, then search for partner by setting heading to closest and moving forward. At the moment they look around but don't go anywhere.